# Receiving empty content / embed from other bot by slash command in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm using Discord.js 14.6.0

When user use **slash command** (/) with **other bot**, I can receive message, but the `embeds` and `content` are empty.
(I can get `embeds` and `content` when bot send normal message)

I've already checked "Privileged Gateway Intents > MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT" in Discord Bot setting

[image: bot setting]

And here's my code:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits , Partials , EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
    partials: [Partials.Channel],
});

client.login(TOKEN);

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Server is on!")
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    console.log(message)
    // When using slash commamd by other Bot, `message.content` result: []
});
```

Comment: A slash command is not a `message` but an `interaction`.

Comment: I've tried `client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {console.log(interaction)});` but it didn't return anything.

Comment: `Events.InteractionCreate` works when user using my bot, But I need to get content when user using another bot.
Using `messageCreate` will get message when user using another bot, but the `message.content` is empty